# how to call .wasm methods in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, webassembly

I have wasm file in which there is function which I want to call in angular so I don't know why It always give me mismatsh signature: I think that the type must be in i32 so how can i do that in angular i even tried this format 00000000000000000000000000000001 32bit but no way

This is the function call in angular

```
 ngOnInit() {
      let test =  new createWasm();
 
      let t2 = new invoke_v(0x2);
}
```

this is the function in the js file

```
function invoke_v(index) {
  var sp = stackSave();
  try {
    dynCall_v(index);
  } catch(e) {
    stackRestore(sp);
    if (e !== e+0 && e !== 'longjmp') throw e;
    _setThrew(1, 0);
  }
}
```

this is function in wasm

```
func $dynCall_v (;2190;) (export "dynCall_v") (param $var0 i32)
    local.get $var0
    call_indirect
```

Comment: can you share the specific error message that you are seeing?

Comment: mismatching  function signature